# LWJGL on Eclipse under Linux (Xubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, libgdx, lwjgl

I am using Xubuntu and I have a game project based on LibGDX. Running it under Windows works great. But I have installed Eclipse on Linux and when trying to run the project, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/libawt.so already loaded in another classloader
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1931)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1650)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1672)
at org.lwjgl.LinuxSysImplementation.<clinit>(LinuxSysImplementation.java:50)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.createImplementation(Sys.java:126)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:111)
at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.audio.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:72)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:82)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:64)
at cz.vilix.main.Desktop.main(Desktop.java:30)
```

I've tried looking this up on the internet, but I got no results.

The line 30 (where the error occurs) is the line where I try to run the game:

```
new LwjglApplication(game = new Game(), config);
```

Comment: Could you provide your libgdx version, as well as a small project which can reproduce this error with. It might help others trying to understand why you are getting this error.

Comment: The project got large (with about 20 classes) but it can be reproduced with already exported *.jar file (running from terminal). It can be found on my dropbox shared link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8kdfmfrehz86dr/LibGDX_Fade.jar

Comment: You aren't missing anything in the Jar and it runs fine for me on Ubuntu and Windows. What version/distribution of Java are you running on Xubuntu?

Comment: It works on my Ubuntu as well, but not on my Xubuntu. I am using openjdk-7-jre-headless on Xubuntu and Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you display the java -version output from your Xubuntu machine?

Comment: Sure: 
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by Lwjgl attempting to load awt on Linux with the following line:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
```

in their [LinuxSysImplementation](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/LinuxSysImplementation.java)

I see there is a discussion on the [LWJGL forums](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,3599.15.html) about this and a potential solution at the end. They talk about this being an issue with headless, so maybe consider looking at seeing if you can find a different version of Java to use. You can try Oracle's version to see if the issue still exists.

This isn't the best solution, but it seems to be caused by something incorrect with the version of Java you are using and that particular version of Linux.

Edit:

One possible solution might be to put the above line inside a static class initializer of the java file you use to launch libgdx. Really the goal is to get that line of code from throwing an exception, or editing lwjgl to ignore the exception when thrown.

```
public class DesktopLauncher {
    static {
        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] arg) {
        final LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), config);
    }
}
```

Another idea might be to install a different non-headless version of Java on your Xubuntu machine as that seems to suggest awt cannot initialize.

Comment: I am not using java.awt anywhere in the code. What should I do?

Comment: Libgdx uses LWJGL, LWJGL uses java.awt. You may want to report this as a bug directly to LWJGL. I do know (at the time of writting) Libgdx isn't running the latest version of LWJGL due to nobody putting it on Maven.

Comment: Could installing different Java version (IBM instead of OpenJDK) help?

Comment: Yes, that may resolve the issue. You could try Oracle's as well.

Comment: Well I got the same error for Oracles's, IBM's and for the OpenJDK (that I was using before).

Comment: I will setup a machine with xubuntu and see if I can find a way to make it work and update my answer if I find something that works.

Comment: That's very generous. Here is an exported jar of my project, which throws the same error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8kdfmfrehz86dr/LibGDX_Fade.jar

Comment: Okay, this is weird, I don't know what I did, but after installing other java versions I got back to openjdk-7 it started working.

Comment: what does the java -version output to console?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

Comment: I'm going to go out and guess there was a corrupted file... but that is very odd

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem back in first semester. This helped him out a lot. hope it helps you.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2012/03/javalangunsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in.html

Comment: The problem is that I don't have direct control over the libraries the game is using since I leave it to the LibGDX framework.